# ant finished with (non-zero) exit value 1

Tags: ros, android-core, build, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to build and install my android_core and up until now I've managed to get everything working except for an error which occurs during compilation of android_core. Here is the output of "./gradlew debug" in android_core directory:

```
    BUILD FAILED
/home/sam/Development/research/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:818: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/sam/Development/research/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:820: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/sam/Development/research/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:832: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/sam/Development/research/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:278: null returned: 137

Total time: 43 seconds

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':android_tutorial_camera:debug'.
> Command 'ant' finished with (non-zero) exit value 1.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34109/ant-finished-with-(non-zero)-exit-value-1/) by [Sam_h](https://answers.ros.org/users/1955/sam_h/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2012-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

We had the same problem
try this:
android update project --path ./android_tutorial_camera --target android-13
but make sure the target is the API level you want.
This worked for us.
We had to do it a couple of times for different packages.
Good luck

---

Originally posted by [Kat](https://answers.ros.org/users/1982/kat/) with karma: 155 on 2012-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1